# Javascript redirect user when submit button is clicked based on radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

What am trying to accomplish is to redirect user to a new url based on Checkbox value.

Note that I am using unbounce so cannot add url to the radio button it self so am looking for a way to accomplish this with just Javascript/jQuery.

Scenario:

User select radio button > click on submit button and new window will open with url based on radio button checked.

Hoping to see some examples with explanations here.

**Update**

Here is my script.

```
$("#buttonID").on('click', function(){
switch ($("input[name=radioName]:checked")){
    case "ValOne":
        window.open("https://example.com?string1");
        break;
    case "valTwo":
        window.open("https://example.com?string2");
        break;
    case "ValThree":
        window.open("https://example.com?string3");
        break;
    case "valFour":
        window.open("https://example.com?string4");
        break;
    default: 
        break;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just take the value of the radio button and depending on which value you open a new window with the corresponding url:

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){
    switch ($("input[name=radioname]:checked")){
        case "radio_value_a":
            window.open("http://google.com");
            break;
        case "radio_value_b":
            window.open("http://yahoo.com");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and great example, your solution seem to work, only issue am having is that the value is not getting passed to the button when clicked.